# ASP.NET MVC - Using XDocument - br tag displaying as text on screen

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document which contains multiple properties and each property has a summary description node. The summary description nodes sometimes contain html 
 tags that I'd like to be used to actually create a line break on the page, but the 
 tags are currently being displayed as text. I'm currently using XDocument in the contr to grab the value of the summaryDescription node and then passing this to the view via a view model.

**XML**

```
<summaryDescription>
A very spacious first floor four bedroom apartment situated in a convenient location. The apartment has a very impressive accommodation comprising main entrance foyer leading to hall, formal lounge, well appointed kitchen breakfast area and TV common room, family bathroom and en-suite shower room.<br/><br/>
</summaryDescription>
```

**Controller**

```cs
var query = (from props in xml.Descendants("property")
             select new PropertyResult
             {
                 Description = props.Element("summaryDescription").Value,
                 PriceText = props.Element("pricetext").Value,
                 Image = "http://www.dezrez.com/estate-agent-software/ImageResizeHandler.do?&photoID=1&AgentID=1239&BranchID=1976&Width=500&PropertyId=",
              }).ToArray();

return View(new ResultsViewModel { Property = query });
```

As you can see the summaryDescription xml node has two line breaks at the end but these are currently being displayed as text on the page. If anyone could help me with forcing the page to see the 
 tags as html tags, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Verify the encoding in the source (with a non-XML editor) and post how `Property` is displayed in the View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your razor view markup, use this Extension method, on your property.

`public static IHtmlString EscapeHTML(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string value)
{
    return new HtmlString(value.ToString());
}`

```
@Html.EscapeHTML(Model.Property)
```